# IE11 does not recognise the rest parameter in vendor.js

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer

While running my angular 7 application in IE11 it gives the following error:

```
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
vendor.js (73764, 26)
```

The line in question is:

```
return function (...args /*, callback*/) {
```

I believe it is because the browser cannot recognise the rest operator. I have exhausted all the suggestions on internet but the problem seems to persist.
Following is the environment I am working on:

```
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.8
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.8
@angular/cli                      7.3.8
@angular/compiler-cli             7.2.13
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.8
@schematics/angular               7.3.8
@schematics/update                0.13.8
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Comment: *"I believe it is because the browser cannot recognise the rest operator."* [Correct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

With refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#Browser_compatibility), we can see that the rest parameter syntax doesn't support IE browser. If we also use the arrow function, it's also not support IE browser, more detail information, please check the [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

As a workaround, we could could [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAWwBQDodQBYCmAggE4DmyAlIgN4BQiiJBUIJS-x5yWzAJiAgEMGAA7MAbvBDIANIghtmYKNQC8APloNGTFmyTiCUuDMQBqBUoIqA3DoC-lew6A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.7.3&externalPlugins=) translate the rest parameter syntax to ES5 syntax.

For example:

```
function sum(...theArgs) {
  return theArgs.reduce((previous, current) => {
    return previous + current;
  });
}

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3));
// expected output: 6

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
// expected output: 10
```

The above code will show the "SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier" error in IE11 browser, after using babel translate, the following code works well in IE11 browser.

```
function sum() {
  for (var _len = arguments.length, theArgs = new Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
    theArgs[_key] = arguments[_key];
  }

  return theArgs.reduce(function (previous, current) {
    return previous + current;
  });
}

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3));
// expected output: 6

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
// expected output: 10
```

Comment: It's the other way around. IE doesn't support the parameters.

Comment: How do I integrate this with webpack 4 and angular 7?

Comment: If the rest parameter part of the code is written by yourself, you could refer to my reply to use babel to translate them to ES5 syntax, then using the translated script in your application. Otherwise, you could try to install [the "plugin-transform-parameters" polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-parameters).